# Regular expression validation for a string

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, validation, typescript

I'm using below code for validating a string using `RegEx`.

```
if(!this.validate(this.form.get('Id').value)) {
  this.showErrorStatus('Enter valid ID');
  return;
}

validate(id) {
  var  patt = new  RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,}$");
  return  patt.test(id);
}
```

Should accept,

```
santosh.jadi
santosh.jadi.others
```

Should not accept,

```
.santosh.jadi
santosh.jadi.
santosh..jadi
```

Can anybody please explain me, what i'm missing?

Comment: Is the dot in the middle optional?

Comment: Is it restricted to lowercase?

Comment: @chrisz No.. both upper and lower allowed

Comment: can there be multiple dots in the middle?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori No. only 1 dot is allowed.

Comment: But is something like `santosh.jadi.other` allowed?

Comment: Put your regexp into a regexp tester like regex101.com. It will provide an English-like description of what the regexp does. Then read that REALLY CAREFULLY. Then write down, in English, exactly what you want your regxp to do. They write a regexp which does that. By the way, `{1,}` is exactly equivalent to `+`.

Comment: @chrisz Yes. its allowed, consecutive dot like `santosh.jadi..other` is not allowed

Comment: OK. Then my second example is what you want, not the first.

Comment: @chrisz Your second example is accepting `santosh.jadi..other
`

Comment: @SantoshJadi I had an extra `+`, you can try it now, it will not match that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works [`^[a-zA-Z]+([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dOw72E/1)

```
if(!this.validate(this.form.get('Id').value)) {
  this.showErrorStatus('Enter valid ID');
  return;
}

validate(id) {
  var  patt  =  new  RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z]+)+$");
  return  patt.test(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`/^[a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/ufKNgo/1):

```
^                           // asserts position at beginning of line
  [a-zA-Z]                  // matches letters
  +                         // matches 1 or more times
  [.]                       // matches a period
  [a-zA-Z]                  // matches letters
  +                         // matches 1 or more times
$                           // asserts position at end of string
```

```js
var rgx = /^[a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+$/gm

console.log(rgx.test('chris.zimmerman'))
console.log(rgx.test('.chris.zimmerman.'))
console.log(rgx.test('chris..zimmerman'))
console.log(rgx.test('ch3ris.zimmerman'))
```

If you want to allow multiple dots, for example `chris.w.zimmerman`, you can use [`^[a-zA-Z]+([.][a-zA-Z]+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/ufKNgo/3)

```js
var rgx = /^[a-zA-Z]+([.][a-zA-Z]+)+$/gm

console.log(rgx.test('chris.zimmerman'))
console.log(rgx.test('chris..zimmerman.'))
console.log(rgx.test('chris.zimmerman.'))
console.log(rgx.test('chris.w.zimmerman'))
```

Comment: This only allows 1 dot. Sounds like there could be multiple as long as they're not consecutive

Comment: @FuzzyTree then shouldn't `santosh.jadi.` be in their accepted list, not rejected?  But to be fair their requirements are fuzzy and they don't cover a lot of cases.

Comment: no because the second dot in that string is at the end

Comment: I believe he is still talking consecutive, he replied to an example `santosh.jadi.other` saying it was valid.

Comment: @chrisz Your second solution is working fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*Regex would be:* /^[a-z]+([.-]?[a-z]+)?$/

*Script:*

```
var text = 'abc.def';
var pattern = /^[a-z]+([\.\-]?[a-z]+)?$/;
if (text.match(pattern)) {
  print("YES!");
} else {
  print("NO!");
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: What's the point of the `?` following `[.-]`? Also, you do not need to escape the period or hyphen inside the character class.

Comment: its not allowing `santosh.jadi.other`